# Javafx getHostServices().getCodeBase() returns an empty string

Tags: javafx

I call getHostServices().getCodeBase() in start method of javafx application but it returns an empty string????.
Both calls from application constructor and from start method return empty string.

```
 public class MyApplication extends Application {

        private HostServices hostService;
        private MyController controller ;
        private Parent root;
        private HostServices hostService;

    public MyApplication() throws IOException  {

        hostService = getHostServices();
        System.out.println("Codebase : "+hostService.getCodeBase() ); // return empty string 

    }

        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

            this.primaryStage = primaryStage;

            try {

                FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(this.getClass().getResource("/mypackage/my.fxml") ); 
                controller = new MyController();
                fxmlLoader.setController(controller);
                fxmlLoader.load();
                root = fxmlLoader.getRoot();

                Scene scene = new Scene(root,1200,1000); 
                primaryStage.setScene(scene);
                primaryStage.show();
                 System.out.println("Codebase : "+getHostServices().getCodeBase() ); // return empty string 

            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

This is very strange situation since the application deployed to the web it is important to get the codebase.

Comment: I use eclipse to develop and test run and then deploy, so when I just run for test I get empty string, could you explain more thanks.

Comment: OK even in start method the same result empty string??

Comment: After packaging and deploying it return the correct host name the problem I think with eclipse when test the application I mean using run command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [`hostServices.getCodeBase()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/HostServices.html#getCodeBase--) javadoc:

> If the application is not packaged in a jar file, this method returns the empty string.

Additionally:

> If the application was launched via a JNLP file, this method returns the codebase parameter specified in the JNLP file.

For `hostServices.getCodeBase()` to return an expected value, you have to appropriately package your application according to the above guidelines.

The way in which you package your application will vary according to the packaging tools you use, so refer to your tool vendor's documentation for information on packaging an application using your chosen development environment.